# MySQL Request only returning 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, inner-join

I am trying to get all the the fields from `appointments` while also getting the corresponding data from `zipcodes` using the following request:

```
select appointments.*, zipcodes.*
from appointments
inner join zipcodes on appointments.service_zipcode = zipcodes.zip
where customer_id = {$_GET['id']}
```

The problem is that there are multiple appointments and I'm only getting 1 appointment back at a time. The join appears to be working as expected, but like I said, I'm only getting 1 row, rather than the 2 that are expected.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If each appointment does not have a corresponding zipcode, then you need a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: What is the result when you leave out the `inner join zipcodes`?

Comment: I just realized that @FreshPrinceOfSO was on to something. Th zipcode I have in the other appointment, is not in the DB, which means it wouldn't be able to join.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I'll delete the question. Or, if @FreshPrinceOfSO wants to post the comment, which solved the problem, as the answer, I'll accept.

Comment: You should sanitize that GET parameter in the query...